# Why does the `Start-Transcript` cmdlet insert newlines even when I use Write-Host -NoNewline?

Tags: powershell, newline, transcription

From [Start-Transcript](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-6):

> The Start-Transcript cmdlet creates a record of all or part of a
> PowerShell session to a text file. The transcript includes all command
> that the user types and all output that appears on the console.

**Code**

```
cls
$Global:ScriptPath = Split-Path $Script:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path
$Global:ScriptName = $Global:ScriptPathAndName.Replace(($Global:ScriptPath + "\"),"")
$Global:ScriptNameNoExt = $Global:ScriptName.Replace(".ps1","")

Start-Transcript -LiteralPath ($Global:ScriptPath + "\" + (Get-Date -f "yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss") + "_" + $Global:ScriptNameNoExt + ".log") 

foreach ($N in 1..3) {
  Write-Host -NoNewline ("test line " + $N + " ")
}

Write-Host 

Stop-Transcript
```

**Console output - appears as expected**

```
Transcript started, output file is C:\temp\2019-02-06_07-13-43_test.log
test line 1 test line 2 test line 3 
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\temp\2019-02-06_07-13-43_test.log
```

**Transcript content - where did the newlines come from?**

```
**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript start
Start time: 20190206071343
Username: xxx
RunAs User: xxx
Machine: xxx
Host Application: xxx
Process ID: 10092
PSVersion: 5.1.14409.1018
PSEdition: Desktop
PSCompatibleVersions: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.1.14409.1018
BuildVersion: 10.0.14409.1018
CLRVersion: 4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion: 3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion: 2.3
SerializationVersion: 1.1.0.1
**********************
Transcript started, output file is C:\temp\2019-02-06_07-13-43_test.log
test line 1
test line 2
test line 3

**********************
Windows PowerShell transcript end
End time: 20190206071343
**********************
```

Comment: Looks like a bug; I encourage you to report it at https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: Done - created [issue #8836](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/8836)

Comment: If you are executing as SYSTEM on Windows then the line-breaks seem to be related to the width of SYSTEM's default console window.

Comment: There's a [blog post](https://devio.wordpress.com/2009/03/04/setting-powershell-window-width/) which explains why this is so broken and what you might do to avert it.

Comment: `Start-Transcript` isn't duplicating the console output and doesn't respond to console formatting.